Call volume prediction using LSTM and GRU
Machine Learning call volume prediction using LSTM and GRU
I am trying to predict the number of incoming calls using LSTM and GRU I have done all the data preprocessing but upon training the model I getting 0.0 accuracy
what could be the the problem
model_lstm = Sequential()

model_lstm.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(X_train_seq.shape[1], X_train_seq.shape[2]))) # Input layer + 1st hidden layer #

model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')) # 2nd hidden layer #

model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu')) # 3rd hidden layer

model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)) # Output layer

model_lstm.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mae', metrics=['accuracy'])

lstm_history = model_lstm.fit(X_train_seq, y_train_seq, epochs=10, batch_size=10, validation_data=(X_test_seq, y_test_seq))

Epoch 1/10 687/687 [==============================] - 73s 106ms/step - loss: 0.0103 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0097 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10 687/687 [==============================] - 79s 116ms/step - loss: 0.0100 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0107 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10 687/687 [==============================] - 78s 114ms/step - loss: 0.0099 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0092 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10 687/687 [==============================] - 79s 115ms/step - loss: 0.0098 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0091 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10 687/687 [==============================] - 80s 116ms/step - loss: 0.0097 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0091 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10 687/687 [==============================] - 80s 116ms/step - loss: 0.0097 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0091 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10 687/687 [==============================] - 80s 116ms/step - loss: 0.0096 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0090 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10 687/687 [==============================] - 81s 118ms/step - loss: 0.0095 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0090 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10 556/687 [=======================>……] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.0095 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00


The problem is that you are using accuracy as a metric for a regression problem, but accuracy is actually meant for classification, not regression.
You can check the Keras docs for metrics that are appropriate for regression, including mse or mae.

Hi @Noe thank you duly noted and much appreaciated
